# Can you merge [browser] with [web-browser]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

These tags look the same to me:

[browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) -> [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for posting this.  I noticed this the other day when I was performing a bunch of tag maintenance, and it is on my list of things to address.

Prompted by your post, I took a look at the 14 questions currently tagged with [browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser).  All of them are referring to web browsers and not file browsers or media browsers.

As such, I agree that it's a good idea to merge [browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) into [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser).  I can also create a corresponding tag synonym.

---

UPDATE: 2020 October 19

Done!  All questions previously tagged with [browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) now have the [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) tag instead.  Also, the [browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) tag will now be recognized as a synonym of the [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) tag.

Many thanks to community member LWC for bringing this to everyone's attention.

Comment: Thanks! You seem to have enough score for this though, so why don't you just do it to get it over with? Shouldn't it take just a second?

Comment: @LWC Good question. Because I view my role as an elected moderator of our community as one to support the community, and not unilaterally make decisions unless there is an urgent or compelling reason to do so.  After a little time, if there is no dissenting opinion (from other community members or moderators), I will definitely make this change for everyone to enjoy!

Comment: I see your point, but in the grand scheme of things that's why we find ourselves with [months old similar questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4740/what-to-do-with-google-chat) (this specific example is more complicated but hope you get my drift that such questions are at constant risk of being forgotten).

Comment: @LWC Very true. StackExchange (SE) really could use a reminder system to revisit user-specified posts.  Community engagement typically results in slower processes than a ruling monarch or dictator, but hopefully the outcome is better for the community.  I have often wondered if a benevolent monarch/dictator could be the best form of government (thinking on a larger scale), but history reveals great challenges in placing into power monarchs/dictators who are truly benevolent.  Typically, humanity winds up with just the opposite (thinking on a larger scale, and also SE).

Comment: See Plato's [Philosopher king](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher_king) ;-)

Comment: @LWC Funny you mention Plato... I've been wanting to learn more about his philosophies, and your inspiration will likely encourage me to do just that. :)

Comment: I'd say go ahead with the merge (and make "browser" a synonym to "web-browser"; file-browsers are rather called "file managers" and are covered by the `file-management` tag). If a person says "browser", in 99% that refers to web-browsers – and if a person wants to mention a file-browser, in 99% that's done explicitly. TL;DR: 2 mods agree, 4 upvotes from the community (well, including at least 1 of a mod) which is not that "highly active" on meta – I'd say that should suffice ;)

Comment: Ugh… speaking of which: `file-browser` => `file-management`? But that might be a separate thing to discuss (though the former has only a single question using it).

Comment: Quite off topic, but I would like to thank you for enabling me to rejoin Stack Exchange by your rapid response to my swiftly closed plea on this site.

Comment: @JohnBentin You are most welcome!

Comment: @Izzy I completed the requested task for this Meta request.  Good eyes seeing the `file-browser` and `file-management` tags.  I'll create a quick Meta post for those tags now.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket pure accident. I searched for "browser" in tags and saw `file-browser` – and that right after writing about file browsers being tagged `file-management` :D // Thanks! (PS: I've added the `status-completed` tag to the question for you)

Comment: @Izzy Yes, a good chunk of what I work on for this SE I found while I was working on something else on the site (see all the recent tag synonyms as an example!).  Just have to be mindful to not go down the rabbit hole too far, or the work becomes endless!